# calculate w vector of svm with rbf kernel

Tags: java, svm, libsvm

I need to find a way to calculate w vector of SVM with rbf kernel. Refer to libsvm documentation, rbf kernel is defined as :

> RBF:  exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)

I know u is a 1*n array (model.sv_coef)
and v is m*n matrix (model.SVs)

now, I don't know haw could I calculate euclidean distance of u and v ---> |u-v| (one of them is 1-d array and the other is 2-d one)
and after that how could I find a 1*n array which is a w array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*It's urgent!*" - Is that so? Then my hourly wage is USD 500. Before taxes, of course...

Comment: It's your kindness if you can answer me.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to perform the operation you dream of. One cannot calculate d(u, v) as in your case by use of euclidean distance. The dimensions do not match, when you define ANY type of vectors/matrices like you did in your question. u and v are data points, but not the results of some SV-estimation.

Make yourself clear what the dimensions of your vectors/matrices are. Consider using DTW (dynamic time warping) or the like, when you use vectors of different lengths. You can put DTW into the RBF kernel, at least this will give results on a empirical sound basis (but keep in mind DTW violates the triangle inequality).

One more thing: u and v are data points. You should familiarize yourself more with SVM.

Comment: Thank you so much, I know 'v' is the array of support vectors which are data points, but what about 'u'? Isn't it "coefficients for SVs in decision functions"( refer to libsvm doc) ?

Comment: No. Think about what an RBF-kernel actually does. Wikipedia is a good first start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel ... keep in mind that "gamma" is actually $1/(2\sigma^2)$.